# new operator for memory allocation on heap

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, operator-keyword, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was looking at the signature of new operator. Which is:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
```

But when we use this operator, we never use a cast. i.e

```
 int *arr = new int;
```

So, how does C++ convert a pointer of type `void*` to `int*` in this case. Because, even `malloc` returns a `void*` and we need to explicitly use a cast.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is a very subtle difference in C++ between `operator new` and the `new` operator.  (Read that over again... the ordering is important!)

The function `operator new` is the C++ analog of C's `malloc` function.  It's a raw memory allocator whose responsibility is solely to produce a block of memory on which to construct objects.  It doesn't invoke any constructors, because that's not its job.  Usually, you will not see `operator new` used directly in C++ code; it looks a bit weird.  For example:

```
void* memory = operator new(137); // Allocate at least 137 bytes
```

The `new` operator is a keyword that is responsible for allocating memory for an object and invoking its constructor.  This is what's encountered most commonly in C++ code.  When you write

```
int* myInt = new int;
```

You are using the new operator to allocate a new integer.  Internally, the `new` operator works roughly like this:

1. Allocate memory to hold the requested object by using `operator new`.
2. Invoke the object constructor, if any.  If this throws an exception, free the above memory with `operator delete`, then propagate the exception.
3. Return a pointer to the newly-constructed object.

Because the `new` operator and `operator new` are separate, it's possible to use the `new` keyword to construct objects without actually allocating any memory.  For example, the famous *placement new* allows you to build an object at an arbitrary memory address in user-provided memory.  For example:

```
T* memory = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T)); // Allocate a raw buffer
new (memory) T(); // Construct a new T in the buffer pointed at by 'memory.'
```

Overloading the `new` operator by defining a custom `operator new` function lets you use `new` in this way; you specify how the allocation occurs, and the C++ compiler will wire it into the `new` operator.

In case you're curious, the `delete` keyword works in a same way.  There's a deallocation function called `operator delete` responsible for disposing of memory, and also a `delete` operator responsible for invoking object destructors and freeing memory.  However, `operator new` and `operator delete` can be used outside of these contexts in place of C's `malloc` and `free`, for example.

Comment: Step two should be "Invoke the object constructor, if any. If this throws *any exception*, free the above memory and propagate the exception."

Comment: @GMan- Thanks for spotting that!  My bad.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Also, can u recommend me some books where i can find pearls like this?

Comment: @Chander Shivdasani- Glad to help; don't forget to accept the answer. ;-)  This pearl of wisdom is based off of Scott Meyers' discussion of new in "Effective C++, 3rd Edition," which is widely considered one of the best books on C++.  It will transform you from a good C++ coder to a GREAT C++ coder and expose you to all sorts of cool ideas that you never would have imagined could be expressed in C++.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i will definitely get a copy of it.

Answer (score 5):

You confuse `new` expression with `operator new()` function. When the former is compiled the compiler among other stuff generates a call to `operator new()` function and passes size enough to hold the type mentioned in the `new` expression and then a pointer of that type is returned.

Comment: To whoever downvoted - what's wrong with this answer?  It seems perfectly correct.