# Memory alignment and strict aliasing for continuous block of raw bytes

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, standards

I have a question about using same continuous block of raw bytes as storage of various typed objects from the point of C++ standard rules.
Consider we create continuous block of raw bytes, f.e.

```cpp
void *data = ::operator new(100); // 100 bytes of raw data - not typed
```

Could then we use this memory like:

```cpp
template<class T>
T* get(std::size_t bshift)
{
    return static_cast<T*>(
        reinterpret_cast<void*>(
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + bshift
        )
    );
}
```

1. Is it safe or UB? Why?

```cpp
float &fvalue2 = *get<float>(sizeof(float));
fvalue2 = 0.02f;
```

2. Is it safe or UB? Why?

```cpp
float &fvalue_reserve = *get<float>(sizeof(float)*2 + 1);
fvalue = 0.03f;
```

3. Is it safe or UB? Why?

```cpp
double &dvalue = *get<double>(sizeof(float)*3 + 1);
dvalue = 0.04;
```

4. Is it safe or UB? Why?

```cpp
// assume that somehow there is no unused internal padding in struct
struct POD_struct{
    float fvalue1;                   //[0..sizeof(float)]
    float fvalue2;                   //[sizeof(float)..sizeof(float)*2]
    char reserved[sizeof(float) + 1];//[sizeof(float)*2..sizeof(float)*3+1]
    double dvalue;                   //[sizeof(float)*3+1..sizeof(float)*3+1+sizeof(double)]
};

POD_struct pod_struct;
std::memcpy(&pod_struct, get<void*>(0), sizeof(POD_struct));
pod_struct.fvalue2 == 0.02f; //true ??
pod_struct.dvalue == 0.04f; //true ??
```

5. Is it safe or UB? Why? is it any different from №4?

```cpp
// assume that somehow there is no unused internal padding in struct
struct POD_struct{
    float fvalue1;                   //[0..sizeof(float)]
    float fvalue2;                   //[sizeof(float)..sizeof(float)*2]
    char reserved[sizeof(float) + 1];//[sizeof(float)*2..sizeof(float)*3+1]
    double dvalue;                   //[sizeof(float)*3+1..sizeof(float)*3+1+sizeof(double)]
};

POD_struct pod_struct;
std::memcpy(&pod_struct, get<POD_struct*>(0), sizeof(POD_struct));
pod_struct.fvalue2 == 0.02f; //true ??
pod_struct.dvalue == 0.04f; //true ??
```

6. Would it make any significant difference if we "fill" memory pointed by `data` pointer not from zero offset (f.e. 1, 2, 3?) and then `memcpy` to POD_struct object from that offset?
7. Is it safe to assume that if we manage required size of continuous block of raw memory buffer to fit all POD members without paddings (aligned by 1 byte) then it's ok to interpret it as any POD type? Is it safe to reuse raw memory and interpret it as another POD type storage since we done using it?

Comment: Why `static_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(` instead of just `reinterpret_cast<T*>`?

Comment: @user17732522 cause C++ WD n4527 5.2.10/7 would allow this to be condensed as "An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of
object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is static_cast<cv
T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)). Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to
T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than
those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value."

Comment: I don't understand what you want to tell me with the quote. `reinterpret_cast<void*>` followed by `static_cast<T*>` here is equivalent to just `reinterpret_cast<T*>`. Also, I don't see any difference in 4. and 5.

Comment: `#pragma pack(push, 1)` makes all of this implementation-defined at best, but already 1. has undefined behavior. Even if you remedy this by explicitly creating the correct objects (and/or using `std::launder`), 2. most likely violates the alignment requirements of `float` and is therefore UB no matter what.

Comment: @user17732522 how far I understand WD n4527 5.2.10/7: it allows to just skip ```reinterpret_cast<T*>``` if ```T``` is also ```unsigned char``` in ```get``` function, I dont fully understand what difference this makes though. Are 4 and 5 equal in terms of memory aliasing and alignment?

Comment: I see the difference in the code snippets for 4. and 5. now, I just didn't notice the difference.

Comment: I don't understand what "_it allows to just skip reinterpret_cast<T*> if T is also unsigned char_" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @user17732522 In case of ```get<unsigned char>(...)``` compiler is not allowed to interpret ```get``` body as simple ```return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + bshift```. As I mensioned earlier I do not fully understand what difference this disallowance makes.

Comment: @user17732522 why 1 is UB? BC data points to non-typed memory? If so would it make it defined behavior if we make ```data = new unsigned char(100)``` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is unclear from your question, but I will assume that there is no other code inbetween the individual snippets you are showing.

Snippet 1. has undefined behavior because the pointer `get` will return cannot actually be pointing to a `float` object. `::operator new` does implicitly create objects and return a pointer to a suitable created object, but that object would have to be a `unsigned char` object part of an `unsigned char` array in order to give the pointer arithmetic in `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + bshift` defined behavior.

However, then the return value of `get<float>(sizeof(float));` would also be a pointer to an `unsigned char` object. Writing through a `float` glvalue to a `unsigned char` violates the aliasing rules.

This could be remedied by either using `std::launder` before returning the pointer from `get` or better by explicitly creating the object:

```
template<class T>
T* get(std::size_t bshift)
{
    return new(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + bshift) T;
}
```

Although this will create a new object with indeterminate value each time it is called.

`std::launder` would be sufficient here without creating a new object since `::operator new` can implicitly create an `unsigned char` array which provides storage for a `float` object which is also implicitly-created. (Assuming all objects used in this way fit in the storage, are correctly aligned (see below), do not overlap and are [*implicit-lifetime types*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Implicit-lifetime_types)):

```
template<class T>
T* get(std::size_t bshift)
{
    return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + bshift));
}
```

However, 2. and 3. have undefined behavior even with this modification if `alignof(float) != 1` (which is very likely to be true). You cannot create and start the lifetime of an object with wrong alignment either implicitly or explicitly. (Although it may technically be possible to create an object with wrong alignment explicitly without starting its lifetime.)

For 4. and 5., assuming the above weren't undefined behavior due to misalignment or out-of-bounds access and given the assumptions in the question, I think these snippets should have defined behavior. Note however that it is *extremely unlikely* that these requirements are satisfied.

For 6., if you offset everything you need to again take care not to go out-of-bounds of the allocation and not to violate the alignment of any of the involved types. (Including the alignment of `POD_struct` for 5.)

For 7. the formulation is very vague, so I am not sure what you mean. But you explicitly generally can't *interpret* memory as a different type than it is. In your examples 4. and 5. you are *copying* object representations, which is different.

---

To be clear again: Practically speaking your code has UB due to the alignment violations. This probably extends even to platforms that allow unaligned access, because the compiler may optimize code based on the assumption of pointer alignment. Compilers may offer type annotations to indicate that a pointer may be unaligned. You need to use these or other tools if you want to implement unaligned access in practice.

Comment: _You cannot create an object with wrong alignment either implicitly or explicitly._ Why not explicitly? I'd say its lifetime just won't start.

Comment: Note that C++20 introduces _impicit object creation_. Which, I believe, makes case 1 correct in C++20 even without placement new and laundering.

Comment: for 4 to 7 - assuming there is no ```pragma pack``` and structure still has no internal padding, could you elaborate more on that cases please?

Comment: @DanielLangr I did consider implicit object creation in my answer. This is why `std::launder` would work as an alternative.

Comment: @AlexanderG. Assuming the alignment requirements for 2. and 3. were fulfilled (extremely unlikely), then I guess the code would have defined behavior as you expect with my modification to `get`. Whether 4. or 5. is chosen doesn't matter.

Comment: @user17732522 I have removed ```pragma``` to make my Q more clear. Thank you for your detailed answer. One more question: could I assume that in all cases if memory address is matching alignment requirements of type in ```get``` than it is safe to perform such conversions and using typed pointer that was returned from ```get```?

Comment: Point 7. it is a bit vague, but that is probably wrong in any case.

Comment: as for implementing ```get``` as explicit creation of object with ```new``` - does that mean that https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436956/6419156 answer is not correct? I have implemented my ```get``` as ```get_location``` from that example since it seemed right.

Comment: @AlexanderG. Haven't read the answers in detail, but yes they seem to have UB as far as I can tell. Even says so in the top answer.

Comment: @AlexanderG. Your question is tagged language-lawyer, but I have extended the answer with a note on behavior in practice. You need to be very careful with unaligned access. If an access is not in some way marked as unaligned access via some compiler-specific feature, it is probably going to be able to cause trouble.

Comment: @user17732522 I completely understand that - therefor are my questions. I want to make things right and understand what loopholes memory managing in C++ has.